# Java enums - choice between fields, abstract methods, and class level map

Tags: java, oop, enums

I have written a Java enum where the values have various attributes. These attributes could be stored in any of the following ways:

**Using fields:**

```
enum Eenum {
  V1(p1),
  V2(p2);

  private final A attr;

  public A attr() { return attr; }

  private Eenum(A attr) {
    this.attr = attr;
  }
}
```

**Using abstract methods:**

```
enum Eenum {
  V1 {
    public A attr() { return p1; }
  },

  V2 {
    public A attr() { return p2; }
  }

  public abstract A attr();
}
```

**Using class level map:**

```
enum Eenum {
  V1,
  V2;

  public A attr() { return attrs.get(this); }

  private static final Map<Eenum, A> attrs;

  static {
    ImmutableMap.Builder<Eenum, A> builder = ImmutableMap.builder();
    builder.put(V1, p1);
    builder.put(V2, p2);
    attrs = builder.build();
  }
}
```

How should I decide when to prefer which?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you should first explain how do they relate (`Eenum` and `A`).

Comment: @BheshGurung, they're just some randomly chosen names. `A` is some random type. If they were related in some way, I would explicitly state so.

Comment: I wonder who voted to close and why.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, there's an error in the class level map variant in the Map declaration (map needs 2 generic parameters).

Comment: @Ubeogesh, you're right. Oversight. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I am answering my own question so that I can share some things I learned while trying out things.)

Here are the questions you should ask to come at a decision for your specific case:

**1: Do the attribute values involve forward references?**

Sometimes `V1`'s attribute may need a reference to `V2` and vice versa. This is not a rare case. If you are dealing with such an `enum`, approach 1 simply would not work. The compiler will (rightly) complain about illegal forward references. Any of the other two approaches can be used.

Now, if the attribute value is expensive to compute and a constant, you'd want that it's computed only once. With approach 2, you'd have to introduce local variables per enum value, and cache results there. This is verbose but will give you better performance. With approach 3, the results are anyway computed only once, and so don't have to do any extra work. This is more readable but somewhat less performant than approach 2. Design between these as per the specific trade offs warranted in your case.

**2: Do I need to cache results?**

Refer to the second paragraph of previous bullet.

If there are no forward references, you can use approach 1 too. But if the computation involved in calculation of attributes is complex, you are better off with one of the other two approaches.

**3: Are the attributes relevant for all of the enum values?**

If not, then quite logically, you should be using a `Map` here. That is, approach 3.

**4: Are there any default values for some attributes for some enum values?**

If so, you can use all three approaches, and they all offer different set of trade-offs.

With approach 1: You would define an auxiliary constructor that initializes the attribute to the default value. If there are multiple such attributes, this might not be a feasible approach.

With approach 2: This will actually be like "fourth" approach Peter Lawrey suggested above. You will have a method returning the default value in `enum`'s main body. And some enum values will override this method to return a different value. This is, again, quite verbose.

With approach 3: Just less efficient. Good in every other way.

Answer (score 3):

I would do the one which you think is the simplest.

In general I don't write code which can be implemented using data. I would use the first one.

> My actual use case has some attributes which are not relevant for all enum values

You can use a combination of these approaches if it makes sense on a per attribute basis.

A fourth option is to not have an abstract method.

```
enum Eenum {
  V1 {
    public A attr() { return p1; }
  },

  V2 {
    public A attr() { return p2; }
  }, 
  V3, V4, V5, V6;

  public A attr() { return defaultA; }
}
```

Comment: Agreed. To me the first solution is simplest and cleanest

Comment: My actual use case has some attributes which are not relevant for all enum values. Would a map be more appropriate in that case?

Comment: My actual use case has some more constraints that make all three approaches more or less of same length.

Comment: @missingfaktor: Why don't you just add the explanation to your question, make it clear.

Comment: @missingfaktor Well without knowing your actual use case it's hard to make a recommendation.

Comment: In the case of not all enum values having an attribute, you could still achieve this with the first solution by passing `null` into those values` constructors. I suppose it depends on how many enum values with attributes there will be.

Comment: Using a Map will be far less efficient even if only a small percentage of enum values than that attribute.

Comment: @BheshGurung, I said "when to prefer which" in OP for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

None of those. Do this:

```
interface HasAttr<T> {
    T attr();
}

enum Eenum implements HasAttr<A> {

    // use "fields" version - ideally with constructor version

    public A attr() {
        return field;
    }

}
```

This pattern follows the fundamental [Abstract Type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_type) design pattern, which allows for method like:

```
public void someMethod(HasAttr<A> hasAttr);  // pass anything that is HasAttr<a>
```

in preference to the fixed type:

```
public void someMethod(Eenum eenum); // locked into passing an Eenum
```

Also, and importantly, it's easier to mock for testing, especially if your enum uses real connections etc.

I grant you, all this only applied if the enum is "nontrivial". If it's just a plain old enum, I agree it's just code bloat (which I also detest)

Comment: Pulling out an interface for every field (I have multiple fields in my actual code) seems pointless.

Comment: Particularly since it won't add any value, for the case I am dealing with.

Comment: @Bohemian want to add an explanation as to why that's better?

Comment: @milkplusvellocet see edited answer - it's just plain old good design

Comment: @missingfaktor see edited answer - it's just plain old good design. Also, you wouldn't have a interface for every field, you would have an interface with all the fields.

Comment: @Bohemian Yeah I get the design pattern, just thought it's worth adding a follow-up to go with your answer.

Comment: While there are cases where this is appropriate, there are also cases where it is just pointless code bloat. Since you don't elaborate when this pattern is appropriate, I don't think this is a useful answer.

Comment: @meriton What do you mean? I gave 2 examples where this pattern is appropriate: Method parameters and mocking. I grant you, this only applied if the enum is "nontrivial". If it's just a plain old enum, I agree it's just code bloat.

Comment: I think this is plain orthogonal to the topic.

Comment: I mostly meant the "None of those. Do this" part, which does seem to claim this approach is always right.